# How to write mapreduce program for counting lines in text file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a .dat file which has n number of lines with multiple fields in one line.
each field is separated by '|'. Now i would like to write a map reduce program to count
number of lines for particular field(same i can do in hive using count(Column_name)).
i am very new to map reduce programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You should first learn the example "word count", then you can know how to deal with your problem.

Here is the example http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/04/word-count-hadoop-map-reduce-example.html